# Simple way to implement a mute button in Android app

Tags: java, android, audio

I am looking for a simple way to implement a mute button.

Obviously I could have a toggle button, `mute_button` and in every instance where a sound is played I could check:

```
if(mute_button.isChecked()){
     //dont play
}else{
    //play the sound
}
```

But I have a lot of instances that I would need to sort through and add this in. Is there a simpler way of something along the lines of:

```
    mute_button.setOnClickListener() ...

onClick
    if(isChecked){
        //set entire application to mute mode
    }else{
       //keep default application sound settings
    }
```

So, really I am looking for a "higher level" or application wide mute, rather than checking if a button is checked every single time a sound may play.

Comment: Could you just set the volume of the device to 0 on button click? If not, then your method is probably the best. I would create a global variable like `systemIsMuted` and a function to call every time you want to play an audio file, that way it minifies the code and there is only one mute check

Comment: wouldn't that affect the other applications running? Let's say the user is also listening to a music app in the background, I wouldn't want to mute the entire device

Comment: It would, but I didn't know if it would work for your purposes or not. Then your best bet is a global variable and a utility class you reference for all your audio calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by setting the media volume to zero

```
MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundSound);
//media.setVolume(leftVolume , rightVolume);
media.setVolume(0 , 0);
```

For soundpool you can try like this:

```
soundpool.setVolume(streamID, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: I am using soundpool instead of MediaPlayer. Maybe I can set the volume level to a static int and just change that int when mute is toggled? hm.. I'll have to think about it. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @MikeJamesJohnson .. updated to mute for soundpool as well

Comment: What if you want to do this from a different activity?